# Error in Angular with the ToggleButton ($event) -- Emit an Event

Tags: angular, event-handling, frontend

I program a button to close and open up a sidebar.

so in the default.component**.html** I will receive the event:

```
<app-header (toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler($event)"></app-header>
```

In Typescript Module default.component.ts I program a function:

```
sideBarOpen = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
    sideBarToggler() {
      this.sideBarOpen = !this.sideBarOpen;
    }
```

The header where the button is to close and open the sidebar is in the header.component.ts:
From this module the user click and the event will send to the other module names default.component**.html.

```
@Output() toggleSideBarForMe: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

    toggleSideBar() {
      this.toggleSideBarForMe.emit();

   
  }
```

Now in the console you can see the error:

> ERROR in src/app/layouts/default/default.component.html:1:50 - error
> TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
>
> ```
> 1 <app-header (toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler($event)"></app-header>
>                                                    ~~~~~~
>
>   src/app/layouts/default/default.component.ts:5:16
>     5   templateUrl: './default.component.html',
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     Error occurs in the template of component DefaultComponent.
> ```

So what is the problem actually?  I tried to fix the problems several time but didn't find out how it works. I'm very new to Angular. Thanks

Eden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in below code, you are passing an argument `$event`

```
(toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler($event)"
```

But at function level, you don't receive it or handle it.

```
 toggleSideBar() {                    // no receiving parameter
  this.toggleSideBarForMe.emit();
 }
```

**Solution**

Either remove `$event` from html

```
(toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler()"
```

**OR**

add a receiving parameter to your function as below,

```
 toggleSideBar(event) {              // event (receiving parameter) added
  this.toggleSideBarForMe.emit();
 }
```

Comment: Hello Micronyks, that was the error!! Thanks, you fix my problems.... I remove the $event from the .html file and then no error appears on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing $event as argumennt from html but not defined in definition of function.
**default.component.ts**

```
  sideBarOpen = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
  sideBarToggler(event) { // add event argument here.
    this.sideBarOpen = !this.sideBarOpen;
  }
```

**OR** remove from template

```
<app-header (toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler()"></app-header>
```

Comment: yeah that was the problem. i remove the events in the argument and then it works smoothly. Thanks for your big help.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding `sideBarToggler($event)` in the template, but the event handler in the controller (`sideBarToggler()`) has no parameters.

Since you don't use the event, it's better to remove the argument in the template.

```html
<app-header (toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler()"></app-header>
```

**Or** if all you do in the handler is to toggle the variable, you could do it directly in the template.

```html
<app-header (toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarOpen = !sideBarOpen"></app-header>
```

The `sideBarToggler()` handler isn't required anymore.

Comment: thanks you very much Michael for your quick answer!!!

Comment: @eden1996: Forgot to mention one more thing, adding parameter to the handler `sideBarToggler(event)` doesn't make sense here since you don't emit any event in the emitter: `this.toggleSideBarForMe.emit()`.